# tomcat7-maven-plugin to deploy spring boot with appropriate spring profile selected

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, pom.xml, maven-tomcat-plugin

My goal is to be able to use the tomcat-maven plugin to deploy my spring boot application from the command line where an argument is supplied that tells spring which profile to use like this:

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

I've tried several different things such as  the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021603/specify-alternative-spring-application-properties-in-maven-pom) but the default application.properties is still always selected.

The only way that I've been able to get the application-dev.properties selected is by using

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"`

But we don't want to have tomcat packaged in our war

I'm new to maven and spring boot and I've been spinning my wheels for the better part of a a day now so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue and I was able to get the correct profile selected using 
`export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev`.  The problem that I was having was when I was starting my local tomcat server through the eclipse UI my environment variables were being ignored.  When starting tomcat through startup.bat the environment variable gets used and spring uses the correct profile.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [MAVEN_OPTS](http://maven.apache.org/configure.html) environment variable to set VM argument. (Linux/osx) example you would need to execute before your maven goal:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer while I think this might work the goal is to be able to set this at run time while setting a maven environment variable would be at build time.  I found that `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev` works but when starting the server in eclipse  these environment variables get ignored